# ITextSharp-generated ComboBox is always "Visible but doesn't print"

Tags: pdf, combobox, itext

I've created a combo box using iTextSharp but the combo is not visible on print. I have tried setting the flags to no avail.

```
foreach (XElement choices in xElement.Elements())
{
    optionList.Add(choices.Attribute("displayName").Value);
}
string[] optionArray = optionList.ToArray();
PdfFormField combo = PdfFormField.CreateCombo(writer, true, optionArray,0);
combo.SetWidget(new Rectangle(sectionX +10+ textLength + 2, fieldIncrementer-3,
        sectionX + Convert.ToSingle(xElement.Parent.Attribute("width").Value),
        fieldIncrementer + FontSize-3), PdfName.HIGHLIGHT);
combo.FieldName = xElement.Attribute("name").Value;
combo.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);

writer.AddAnnotation(combo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue by making my combo a different way. Below is my updated code:

```
foreach (XElement choices in xElement.Elements())
    {
     optionList.Add(choices.Attribute("displayName").Value);
    }
    string[] optionArray = optionList.ToArray();

 var _text = new TextField(writer,
 new Rectangle(sectionX + 10 + textLength + 2, fieldIncrementer - 3,
 sectionX + Convert.ToSingle(xElement.Parent.Attribute("width").Value),
 fieldIncrementer + FontSize - 3), xElement.Attribute("name").Value.Trim());
 _text.Choices = optionArray;
 writer.AddAnnotation(_text.GetComboField());
```

Comment: That's indeed the best workaround. I'm adding my own answer that explains that you didn't experience a bug in iTextSharp, but that you were using iTextSharp incorrectly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've solved the problem and I upvoted your answer, because it's indeed easier to use the convenience object `TextField` than to create the `PdfFormField` yourself.

For the sake of completeness, I'm adding an extra answer to clarify what went wrong initially.

In the following line, you mixed two concepts:

```
combo.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
```

A field is described in a field dictionary and you can define field flags to make the field read only, required, multi-select, etc... You can find the value of the field flags in the `/Ff` entry of the field dictionary.

Each field corresponds with zero, one or more widget annotations. Widget annotations are the visual representation of the field and they are described using an annotation dictionary. You can define annotation flags, for instance to define the visibility of such an annotation. You can find the annotation flags in the `/F` entry of the annotation dictionary.

When one field corresponds with one widget annotation (which is the case for most forms), the field dictionary and its widget annotation's dictionary are merged into one dictionary. This dictionary can have an `/Ff` and an `/F` entry.

In your code, you're defining an annotation flag as a field flag. You're putting a value meant to be in the `/F` entry into the `/Ff` entry. This is wrong and it explains why your code "doesn't work." You're actually making your field dictionary corrupt by replacing existing values by a value that has a completely different meaning.

You should use the following line to correct your code:

```
combo.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
```

This way, you're changing the `/F` value, using the `/Ff` value intact.

Comment: Hey Bruno, thanks for the help. I see why that makes sense! Thanks!